# What is the thickness criteria to consider a beam with changing thickness Continuous?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, design, structural-analysis

I have a beam as shown below that have a span having 60 cm in thickness and the other spans 30 cm do I consider this beam as continuous or does the changing in thickness affect that ? if there is anything like an article about these criteria (especially in ACI code) 
[image: Span 3 with changing thickness]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is still continuous; all beams are still capable of producing a hogging moment above the columns.

Comment: Is there any limit from which I can't consider the beam in span 3 as continuous and analysis it as a simply supported ?

Comment: No. It is nothing to do with relative thickness and all to do with how the connection is detailed. If both beams are connected together/to the column with full moment connections then the beam is continuous.